# using assert in struct to assure denominator of fraction is non zero

Tags: c, struct

I was making a struct of type fraction and I want to assert that my denominator is not zero
I tried using `assert(denom!=0);` in my struct but it's showing

```
expected a type specifierC/C++(79)
#define assert(expression) (void)( (!!(expression)) || (_wassert(_CRT_WIDE(#expression), _CRT_WIDE(__FILE__), (unsigned)(__LINE__)), 0) )
Expands to:

(void)( (!!(denom !=0)) || (_wassert(L"denom !=0", L"E:\\Aditya 2k22_a2_29_C programs\\Algorithm and Datastructure\\euclidalgo.c", (unsigned)(7)), 0) )
```

but
assert(fraction_name.denom!=0); works fine if I use it in int main()

here's my code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <assert.h>
    struct Fraction
    {
        int num;    
        int denom;
        assert(denom !=0);   
    };
```

Comment: It is a statement. In cannot be placed like that in a stuct, only in code that gets executed at a specific time (like `main` or any other function).

Comment: If you have a `create_fraction()` function, put it in there.

Comment: This is the kind of thing you can do in an OO language. You can define a method that's used to update the `denom` field, and it can perform checks like this.

Comment: Note that `assert()` is not a replacement for validation in your code. It's a debugging tool, but it should be disabled in production code.

Comment: `assert(...)` is a piece of code that has to run in order to check the condition and show a message if the condition is not met. Ask yourself _when_ the assertion code is run in your original code from the question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot place `assert` in a struct - only variable declarations are allowed in structs.

To solve the issue, you can create a function which creates fractions, and put the `assert` there:

```
struct Fraction create_fraction(int numerator, int denominator) //doesn't have to be create_fraction, can be any name
{
   assert(denominator != 0);

   struct Fraction f;
   f.num = numerator;
   f.denom = denominator;

   //other behavior

   return f;
}
```

You can use this as so:

```
struct Fraction myFraction = create_fraction(4, 3); //"creates" 4/3
```